# Python: creating a class that could be iterated circularly

Tags: python, iterator, circular-list

I want to create, in Python,  a class behaving like a list but that could be iterated circularly
use case example:

```python
myc = SimpleCircle()
print(len(myc))
j = iter(myc)
for i in range (0, 5):
    print(next(j))
```

it will print 
a
b
c
d
a

the code I tried so far is the one below
I know the issue is with my `__next__`

method
which by the way seems ignored, I can use next even if I don't implement it

```python
class SimpleCircle:
    def __init__(self):
        self._circle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        self._l = iter(self._circle)


    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._circle)

    def __iter__(self):
        return (elem for elem in self._circle)

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            elem = next(self._l)
            idx = self._circle.index(elem)
            if idx < len(self._circle):
                return elem
            else:
                return self._circle[0]
        except StopIteration:
            pass
```

Comment: Are you trying to implement [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually already exists with [**`itertools.cycle`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), for example:

```
from itertools import cycle

for x in cycle(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']):
    print(x)
```

will keep repeating the element.

Next you here mix up the iterable, and the iterator, those are frequently different things.

As an iterable we can keep iterating from `self._circle`:

```
class SimpleCircle:
    def __init__(self):
        self._circle = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._circle)

    def __iter__(self):
        if not self._circle:
            raise StopIteration
        while True:
            yield from self._circle
```

Or for an *iterator*:

```
class CycleIterator:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterator = iter(iterable)
        self.__next__ = self._iternext
        self.idx = 0
        self.list = []

    def _iternext(self):
        try:
            x = next(self.iterator)
            self.list.append(x)
            return x
        except StopIteration:
            self.__next__ = self._iterlist
            return self._iterlist()

    def _iterlist(self):
        try:
            return self.list[self.index]
        except IndexError:
            raise StopIteration
        finally:
            self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.list)
```

Comment: That's very clear, thank you. About the mixing of iterable and iterator, if I'm understanding well if I want a class iterable I've just to implement __iter__ , instead if I want to implement an iterator class I've to implement __next_

Answer (score 2):

Here's a basic non-itertools implementation:

```
class CyclicIterable:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = list(data)

    def __iter__(self):
        while True:
            yield from self._data

cycle = CyclicIterable(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
for i, x in zip(range(5), cycle):
    print(x)
```

Notice that there's no need to implement `__next__` since the `Cycle` class itself, just like `list`, *is not an iterator.* To get an iterator out of it explicitly, you write:

```
it = cycle.__iter__()
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
print(next(it))
```

Of course, you can instantiate as many iterators as you'd like.

Comment: There's no need for the generator expression in your `yield from` line. `yield from (x for x in self._data)` is just the same as `yield from self._data`  (but slower and harder to understand).

Comment: @Blckknght Whoops I forgot to remove that when copying from OP :P

Comment: Very clever implementation. It took me a while to understand what happens. Would you please consider writing a small description why/how it cycles?

Comment: It's equivalent to `while True: for x in self._data: yield x`.